# yup validation schema for number with two decimal places and 0 input allowed

Tags: validation, yup

```
export const NumberWithTwoDecimalPlaces = Yup.number()
  .typeError("Must be numeric")
  .nullable()
  .transform((value: number, originalValue: string) =>
    // allow empty strings (avoids casting to NaN)
    originalValue === "" ? null : value
  )
  .test(
    "decimal-places",
    "Incorrect value",
    (val: number | null | undefined) => val == null || /^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test((val || "").toString())
  );
```

This almos works as expected apart from fact that I cant provide 0 as input and this should be valid. when providing 0 I am getting "Incorrect value", Please help

Answer (score 0):

To create a `validation schema` for a number with two decimal places where 0 input is allowed, you can use a regex pattern like this:

```
^(?:0|\d*\.\d{1,2})$
```